# Windows Server 2012 Call Command Doesn't Work

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have the `sendmail.bat` script below that used to work in Windows 2003 but now does nothing in Windows 2012.

The `Win32SendMail.pl` script takes five args [smpt_host,from,to,subject,email_body].

I can still run it from the PowerShell terminal but when used inside of a .bat script (see below) it doesn't send out the email, didn't returned errors either. Any ideas on how to resolve this?

```
call perl.exe Win32SendMail.pl 192.168.101.10 sender@localhost me@myemail.com
    my_subject email_body.txt
```

Comment: Is what appears as the second line of code in your question (`my_subject email_body.txt`) actually on a different line to the rest of the command, or is that just for aesthetics?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a native method to send an email from a batch file, using VBS.

It can be called from the command line too - see comments inside the script:

```
:: email.bat :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
@echo off
setlocal

:: use these settings to send from a gmail account
:: set port=465 and set SSL=True

:: use these settings for standard email SMTP port and no encryption
:: set port=25 and set SSL=False

:: Change these following items to use the same variables all the time
:: or use the command line to pass all the variables

set Port=25
set SSL=False
set From="myemail@myemailserver.com"
set To="recipient@server.com"
set Subject="Subject line"
set Body="Email Body in one line"
set SMTPServer="mailservername.myemailserver.com"
set User="username"
set Pass="password"
set fileattach="d:\myfolder\file.txt"


:: This section sets the command line arguments
:: use this format:  CALL email.bat "myname@gmail.com" "RecipientEmailAddress@server.com" "Subject line" "Email Body in one line" "smtp.gmail.com"  "myname@gmail.com" "password" "d:\folder\filename to attach.txt"


if "%~7" NEQ "" (
set From="%~1"
set To="%~2"
set Subject="%~3"
set Body="%~4"
set SMTPServer="%~5"
set User="%~6"
set Pass="%~7"
set fileattach="%~8"
)

set "vbsfile=%temp%\email-bat.vbs"
del "%vbsfile%" 2>nul
set cdoSchema=http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration
echo >>"%vbsfile%" Set objArgs       = WScript.Arguments
echo >>"%vbsfile%" Set objEmail      = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
echo >>"%vbsfile%" objEmail.From     = %From%
echo >>"%vbsfile%" objEmail.To       = %To%
echo >>"%vbsfile%" objEmail.Subject  = %Subject%
echo >>"%vbsfile%" objEmail.Textbody = %body%
if exist %fileattach% echo >>"%vbsfile%" objEmail.AddAttachment %fileattach%
echo >>"%vbsfile%" with objEmail.Configuration.Fields
echo >>"%vbsfile%"  .Item ("%cdoSchema%/sendusing")        = 2 ' not local, smtp
echo >>"%vbsfile%"  .Item ("%cdoSchema%/smtpserver")       = %SMTPServer%
echo >>"%vbsfile%"  .Item ("%cdoSchema%/smtpserverport")   = %port%
echo >>"%vbsfile%"  .Item ("%cdoSchema%/smtpauthenticate") = 1 ' cdobasic
echo >>"%vbsfile%"  .Item ("%cdoSchema%/sendusername")     = %user%
echo >>"%vbsfile%"  .Item ("%cdoSchema%/sendpassword")     = %pass%
echo >>"%vbsfile%"  .Item ("%cdoSchema%/smtpusessl")       = %SSL%
echo >>"%vbsfile%"  .Item ("%cdoSchema%/smtpconnectiontimeout") = 30
echo >>"%vbsfile%"  .Update
echo >>"%vbsfile%" end with
echo >>"%vbsfile%" objEmail.Send

cscript.exe /nologo "%vbsfile%"
echo email sent (if variables were correct)
del "%vbsfile%" 2>nul
goto :EOF
```